# undertow-core unwanted Dependencies

Tags: undertow, jboss-logging

Can I get undertow-core with less dependence?

if I get dependencies of undertow core I get all these jars, does this jars are all required for running an **http server that just serves 3 simple pages**?.

**jdeparser** is a java source code generator, **jboss-classfilewriter** seems to write classes, 5 jars for managing **logging**!. What would expect for a small server in java is a jar with minimal dependencies but it seems that it give me some **dependencies that I don't need**.

```
alpn-api-1.0.0.jar
jboss-classfilewriter-1.0.5.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Final.jar
jboss-logging-processor-1.2.0.Final.jar
jboss-logmanager-1.5.2.Final.jar
jdeparser-1.0.0.Final.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
undertow-core-1.1.3.Final-sources.jar
undertow-core-1.1.3.Final.jar
undertow-parser-generator-1.1.3.Final.jar
xnio-api-3.3.0.Final.jar
xnio-nio-3.3.0.Final.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

The following are not required:

```
undertow-parser-generator-1.1.3.Final.jar
undertow-core-1.1.3.Final-sources.jar
jboss-classfilewriter-1.0.5.Final.jar
jboss-logging-processor-1.2.0.Final.jar
jdeparser-1.0.0.Final.jar
alpn-api-1.0.0.jar
```

These are (mostly) used as annotation processors at build time, and unfortunately maven does not really provide a way to allow you to specify that a dependency is build time only.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, it needs this:

`jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Final.jar
jboss-logmanager-1.5.2.Final.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
undertow-core-1.1.3.Final.jar
xnio-api-3.3.0.Final.jar
xnio-nio-3.3.0.Final.jar`

there still are 5 libs for printing in a log.

Comment: Hi Stuart, do you think the `provided` dependency scope could work here? You need it for compiling but in runtime it assumes that it is in the classpath, but since they are not used at runtime, this shouldnt be a problem?